# how to make htaccess force https for www.example.com and example.com but no other subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a host that has many subdomains and I want to force https (redirect for https ) for www.example.com and example.com but not any other subdomain, how to do this?

currently I am using :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

but this does not work as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a condition using `HTTP_HOST`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond HTTP_HOST ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```